# Set up node so it is externally visible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Newbie question - might be more appropriate for ServerFault, apologies if so.

I'm setting up node on Ubuntu 11.10, following the [excellent howtonode instructions on installing Node](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs).

I can get the Hello World page running on 127.0.0.1:8000, but how do I set it up to appear for my server's external IP?

I'm used to configuring Apache - what's the node equivalent of Apache's "Hello World" page?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Maybe what I need is a tutorial on hosting Node. Would be great if anyone could suggest a good one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no configuration needed to make your external IP address work with node.js, unless and until you bind it otherwise.

Instead of `.listen(PORT, IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST );` use `.listen(PORT);`

Then, just use `IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST:PORT` to access it.

Comment: This answer helped me. I was running a simple node.js http server in a Vagrant VM. I had to specify my IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST as "0.0.0.0" in order for my host to access it.

Comment: I spent hours looking for a way to make node work externally. using listen(80) instead of listen(80, '127.0.0.1') was the solution for me.
Also, make sure apache isn't running (ie /etc/init.d/apache2 stop)

Comment: How can a device access the sites on the server afterwards?

Comment: @MotassemJalal simply by navigating to http://[EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS_OF_SERVER:PORT
Just make sure that if you have a router you configure the port forwarding correctly.

Comment: I tried using this solution but it doesn't work. I call access my app with localhost:port but not ipaddress:port.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up Node to listen on any IP/port, check out http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.3/api/http.html#server.listen

Or a quick modified example from the link you supplied:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(80, "192.168.1.1");

console.log('Server running at http://192.168.1.1:80/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the designated port (8000) is open to reach.

1. check open port with `iptables -L INPUT -v` or `ufw status verbose` to see if that port 8000 is open
2. update rules to open the port `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000-j ACCEPT` or `ufw allow 8000`
3. check again that the rules implemented `iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers` or `ufw status verbose`
4. if still not reachable set host to 0.0.0.0 so it could reach from any ip.
5. the try from your browser to reach the server IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST:PORT