# Change to don't listen to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

When we set up a http server in NodeJS, the default host is `localhost:port`

I'd  like to know how to change this path, and put my server to listen to `http://myHost`
without a port. How would I do this?

Comment: related: [Set up node so it is externally visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325480/set-up-node-so-it-is-externally-visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the port which the browser uses is 80. So, if you change your nodejs app to listen on that port you will not have to add the port in the url. The other part of your question is about changing your *hosts* file.

Under windows 7 the file is located here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

Linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Open the file and add

```
127.0.0.1   myhost.com
```

After that step open *myhost.com* and you will see that it points to the same place as localhost did before.

Have in mind two things:

a) You should stop all other servers run on your system. I.e. Apache, Nginx or something like that. This will release port 80 for your needs.

b) By default node can't listen on lower ports because of security reasons. In general you may use root access to run the node and then it will probably work. However, that's not a good idea. I hope that it is only for your personal needs.

Comment: If my answer helped you I'll be glad if you mark it as successful.