# How can I access my website from other networks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have recently gotten node.JS
All the tutorials I have been looking at tells me to go to local host to view the application, I am using the port 2000. I understand that localhost is also the same as my ip.. 192.168.0.1:2000, I have port forwarded the port 2000 on my modem settings, but the server is still not accessible from other networks. Please help. so how can I access my website from other networks?

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");
```

Comment: Wrong forum, but anyway. When you try accessing it from other networks, you need to use your outgoing IP, not the local. Are you? Also, I suspect your portforwarding is done incorrectly. You need to forward the port 2000 to the machine that hosts the nodejs program. NOT to 192.168.0.1 since that is your routers local ip

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake private ip is actually 192.168.0.2. How do I use my public ip in node js?

Comment: see the link I posted. Also, kindly insert you nodejs code here.

Comment: Ok thanks, still a bit confused though here is code. http://pastebin.com/NvB5ciAh

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing in the code that restricts access from outside your network (I am not an expert though). Could you also insert your port forward rule? Also, could there be a firewall block? For easier testing (instead of running to your mate), turn off wifi and turn on mobile data on your phone and test it that way

Comment: Also, can you try port 3000 instead since that is the default express port

Comment: I think instead of `serv.listen` you want `app.listen`

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that localhost is also the same as my ip.. 192.168.0.1:2000

It isn't. Computers on a network generally have multiple IP addresses.

`localhost` will point to the loopback interface (typically on `127.0.0.1` or `::1`).

`192.168.0.1` is a private IP address (so it is likely to be a machine on your LAN). It is unlikely to be the address of your computer's WiFi or Ethernet interface though. It is normally used by the router.

You need to:

1. Confirm if `192.168.0.1` is the IP address of your computer or not (and get the correct address if so)
2. Make sure that port forwarding is configured to point to the correct address for the correct port
3. Make sure that your Node.js app is listening on the right network interface (you may have written it so it only listens on `localhost`)
4. Make sure that when you try to access it from outside the network, you are using the public facing IP address of your router

Note that some routers won't let you access their external facing IP address from inside the network, so you may have to test from a machine outside your network.

Comment: Sorry typo the private IP address is actually 192.168.0.2. port forward is configured to corrected address. How do I make sure Node.js is listening to the right network interface? Yes I have been testing on machines outside my network. (Friends house across the road)

Comment: @Bob Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325480/set-up-node-so-it-is-externally-visible

Comment: Thanks, still a bit confusing though

Comment: Ive looked at that post but still isnt working. my code is at pastebin.com/NvB5ciAh