# How to use publicIP:3000 in place of localhost:3000 in node.js application

Tags: node.js

i have a dedicated server(Virtual Machine) with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx public IP address,
how to publish node.js application on it ? .
I should be able to browse my application from another PC via internet ,
have no idea , please help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing more of your project but this may have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325480/set-up-node-so-it-is-externally-visible).

> There is no configuration needed to make your external IP address work with node.js, unless and until you bind it otherwise.
>
> Instead of .listen(PORT, IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST ); use .listen(PORT);
>
> Then, just use IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST:PORT to access it.

Edit: It occurred to me that you may not be aware of how the basics of websites work (not trying to insult you here, I just don't know how much work you've done already). Once you have exposed your application to respond on any IP, you need to forward port 80 from your gateway/router/firewall to the internal IP address of your VM running Node.

Comment: var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app)

    

app.use(express.static('public'))

 app.get('/',function(req,res){
     res.send("Ok")
 })   
server.listen(3000);

Comment: That's good, @AbhishekDesai. What happens when you try to hit it from another machine? Have you let port 3000 through on your firewall on your VM and gateway?